# Find the row-wise index of a list of values from numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a smart way to find the index of a list of values in a matrix using `numpy`? We can always do it in iterative way, but is there any quick and fast way available?

We have a matrix as:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

and a list:

```
[3,4,7,11]
```

What we need here is the index of 3,4,7 and 11 in corresponding rows of the matrix, i.e. `[2,0,0,1]`.

It is obviously a simple code to write in iterative approach, but we are looking for any ready implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [Numpy Argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to fetch position of element in a numpy array in a list comprehension(if you want to search for multiple elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example this works:

```
In [17]: import numpy as np

In [18]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])

In [19]: l = [3,4,7,11]

In [20]: np.where(a == np.array(l)[:, None])[1]
Out[20]: array([2, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: wont help if element in search belong to same sub-array, as it only finds first element

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to get you desired indices

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
search_list = [3,4,7,11]
index_arr = [np.argwhere(arr==x).flatten()[1] for x in search_list]
#index_arr [2, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Works fine but I was trying not to use the for loops, rather let the framework perform any optimization if possible.

Comment: @SamGhatak make sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a duplicate-safe version of @Akavall's solution. If there are multiple occurrences of a value the first index is returned:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
b = [3,4,7,11]

# introduce a repeated value 
a[1][1] = a[1][0]
a
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 4, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

i, j = np.where(a == np.c_[b])
j[i.searchsorted(range(len(b)))]
# array([2, 0, 0, 1])
```